# how can render html tags in html5 canvas filltext() method?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

how can render HTML tags in html5 canvas `filltext()` method?

for example here is the rest of the code:

```
context.fillText(
        "label: " + "hossein" + "<br/>" + "id: " + "52" + "<br/>",
        Math.round(node[prefix + 'x'] + size + 10),
            Math.round(node[prefix + 'y'] - 60)
);
```

is correct the `<br>` html tag that I use in code? does it work correct?

if not how must I use that?

Comment: *"does it work correct?"* Didn't you run the code? You should be able to answer that yourself. From the API documentation it seems that `fillText` accepts a `DOMString`, so I highly doubt that HTML will actually be rendered.

Comment: so how can I add html tags to that? I need do that

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas

Answer (score 2):

The `fillText()` method can only take plain text and doesn't parse any tags within it. If your text is as simple as here you can however make your own parser.

```
function myFillText(txt, x, y) {

    // get a pseudo height for the font
    var fontParts = context.font.split(' '),
        fontHeight = parseInt(fontParts.length === 2 ? fontParts[0] : fontParts[1], 10),
        // split the text based on HTML5 line-breaks
        txtParts = txt.split('<br>'),
        i = 0;

    // iteate parts and increase line position for each line
    for(; i < txtParts.length; i++) {
        context.fillText(txtParts[i], x, y + i * fontHeight);
    }
}
```

Now simply use this instead:

```
myFillText("label: " + "hossein" + "<br>" + "id: " + "52" + "<br>",
           Math.round(node[prefix + 'x'] + size + 10),
           Math.round(node[prefix + 'y'] - 60));
```

### [Online demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/kxdpb/)

PS: if you're using HTML5 then you can use `<br>` without the back-slash. The back-slash is for XHTML - or modify the parser to support the other form.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use html tags inside Canvas.  Canvas has its own set of drawing commands.

As you've discovered, one of those drawing commands is fillText.

If you want multi-lines of canvas text, you must do multiple fillText commands and increase the y-coordinate of each succeeding fillText.

```
var x = Math.round(node[prefix + 'x'] + size + 10);

var y = Math.round(node[prefix + 'y'] - 60);

var myLineHeight=16  // space between lines of text

fillText("label: "+"hossein", x,y);

fillText("id: "+"52", x,y+myLineHeight);

fillText("Other stuff", x,y+myLineHeight*2);

fillText("Even more stuff", x,y+myLineHeight*3);
```